# Exception thrown in iOS app using cryptopp static library on XCode 4.6.2

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, crypto++

Here's some detail of what I have.

- Separately compiled crypto++ build and have a static library (libcryptopp.a).
- Created sample single view app and linked against above library, created new group to include crypto++ headers. These headers are NOT copied into the app's target folder.
- Created a new .mm file in the app from which I am executing some sample code which I want to send to the console for now. Note that this sample code is pretty much unmodified from that provided in the test file SymmetricCipher.cpp.

  ---
- Settings under project Build Settings:

  Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 settings
- C Language dialect - GNU99
- C++ Language dialect - GNU++11
- C++ Standard Library - libstdc++

  ---
- Made exact same changes to an existing project and just inserted sample code in existing file to test output. That worked without any problems.
- Code in standalone app throws exception **"EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x20)"**

  ```
    #import "TestView.h"

    //Include C++ headers
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    #include "aes.h"

    // Includes all required Crypto++
    // Block Cipher Headers
    #include "SymmetricCipher.h"

    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>

    // Crypto++ Includes
    #include "modes.h" // xxx_Mode< >
    #include "filters.h" // StringSource and
    // StreamTransformation

    #include "sha.h"
    #include "base64.h"

    #endif


    @implementation TestView

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            // Initialization code
           }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)testBlock
    {

    //Test code
    byte key[ CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];

    ::memset( key, 0x01, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH );
    ::memset( iv, 0x01, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE );

    // Message M
    std::string PlainText = "Yoda said,Do or Do Not. There is no try.";

    // Cipher Text Sink
    std::string CipherText;

    // Encryptor
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption
    Encryptor( key, sizeof(key), iv );

    // Encryption
    CryptoPP::StringSource( PlainText, true,
                     new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter( Encryptor, new             CryptoPP::StringSink(CipherText )) // StreamTransformationFilter
                     ); // StringSource

    // example of hashing followed by base64 encoding, using filters
    std::string digest;

    CryptoPP::SHA256 hash;  // don't use MD5 anymore. It is considered insecure

    CryptoPP::StringSource foo(PlainText, true,
                         new CryptoPP::HashFilter(hash, new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder (new CryptoPP::StringSink(digest))));

    NSLog(@"SHA256 Hash %s", digest.c_str());

    }

    @end
  ```

Comment: How did you build libcryptopp.a??

Comment: You are missing a lot of information, so its hard to say. Can you provide the stack trace? Otherwise, here's a stab in the dark: you have a global Crypto++ object (static storage) and its using the default channel. DEFAULT_CHANNEL is a std::string, and the string is not yet constructed when the object uses it to name the channel. (Its ill-behavior on all OSes, but Mac OS X is particularly bad about initialization across translation units).

Comment: @gotomanners - Sorry for the delayed response. I made some changes to the cryto++ makefiles. You can access them here: https://github.com/nileshkaria/cryptopp

However, please take a look at response below. I believe that might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The Crypto++ code is good. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Instead of trying to cross compile Crypto++, perhaps you should try out [cryptopp-5.6.2-ios on GitHub](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-5.6.2-ios). Its got a pre-built fat library for 6.1 SDK (`armv7`, `armv7s`, `i386`); and a pre-built fat library for 7.0 SDK (`armv7`, `armv7s`, `arm64`, `i386`).

[image: Crypto++/iOS test code]

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for not replying sooner! I'll try that out and see how it goes. 

Any idea how did my code worked when the above steps were applied to an existing project?

Comment: user1028028 - you should probably start a new question and explain where you are having trouble.